# Laravel redirect all http to https

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a website in Laravel which i switched over to https a while ago. I have succeeded to redirect all secure non-www (https://) URL's to www (https://www.) variants with the help of other posts, but am getting stuck on getting both non-secure variants (http://) and (http://www.) redirected to the secure www variants (https://www.)

When you call for the non-secure, www version: 
http://www.apk-vervaldatum.nl,

It redirects to:
https://www.apk-vervaldatum.nl/public/https://www.apk-vervaldatum.nl

When you call for the non-secure, non-www version: 
http://apk-vervaldatum.nl,

It first redirects to:
https://www.apk-vervaldatum.nl

Then redirects to:
https://www.apk-vervaldatum.nl/public/https://www.apk-vervaldatum.nl

My htaccess in the root folder looks is:

```
*Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]*
```

My htacces in public folder looks is:

```
*Options -MultiViews -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On # Handle Authorization Header 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} . 
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] 

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder... 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$ 
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301] 

# Handle Front Controller... 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]*
```

Comment: Have you researched into resolving this inside `nginx` or `apache` config files instead of `.htaccess`?

Comment: Hi Nikola, i did not yet. Since i am not an expert on that field. And i believe it should be fixed through htaccess files first. If not achievable, i will consider other options.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have method how to enforce using HTTPS

Go to `AppServiceProvider`:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        URL::forceScheme('https'); // add this
    }
}
```

Another approach is change is `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried the .htaccess, but this did not work for me.

Comment: did u try with AppServiceProvider?

Answer (score 0):

your .htaccess should be :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Start with www 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]


    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: When i use this, the non-secure, now-www version gets redirected to:
https://www.apk-vervaldatum.nl/public/index.php

Maybe i should change the root htaccess when using this? Now it is:


`Options +FollowSymLinks



RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on

RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`